# How to get return object value from API in ionic 4

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I am using ionic 4. I post the data to my API then I get the return result like this:

```
{
    "responses": [
        {
            "Detection": {
                "Entities": [
                    {"entityId":"1","score":1.05855},
                    {"entityId":"2","score":10.05}
                ],
                "Images": [
                    {"url":"https:URL"}, 
                    {"url":"https:URL"}
                ],
                "Ages": [
                    {"age":"33"}, 
                    {"age":"17"}
                ],
                "Labels":[
                    {"label":"game"}
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My question is how can I get specific data from my API like I want to seperate it to get entities, image, age, and label. Like this
this.entities = entitiesID;

this.score = score;

Here is my code:

By using QuickType, I copied your API response and generated some interfaces in order to get type information:

**random_interface.ts**

```
export interface RandomAPI {
    responses: Response;
}

export interface Response {
    Detection: Detection;
}

export interface Detection {
    Entities: Entity[];
    Images:   Image[];
    Ages:     Age[];
    Labels:   Label[];
}

export interface Age {
    age: string;
}

export interface Entity {
    entityId: string;
    score:    number;
}

export interface Image {
    url: string;
}

export interface Label {
    label: string;
}
```

here is **main code**:

```
onSubmit() {
this.http.post(this._apiURL).subscribe((data: RandomAPI) => {
  this.theTodo = data ;
  this.entities = this.theTodo.responses.Detection.Entities 
  console.log(this.entities);
});
```

}

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/#), I copied your API response and generated some interfaces in order to get type information:

**random_interface.ts**

```
export interface RandomAPI {
    responses: Response[];
}

export interface Response {
    Detection: Detection;
}

export interface Detection {
    Entities: Entity[];
    Images:   Image[];
    Ages:     Age[];
    Labels:   Label[];
}

export interface Age {
    age: string;
}

export interface Entity {
    entityId: string;
    score:    number;
}

export interface Image {
    url: string;
}

export interface Label {
    label: string;
}
```

Now you need to use the `HttpClient` module to load the `http` class (assuming you're using Angular) and use the `get` method from it.

**main code**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RandomAPI } from "./random_interface.ts";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {
  public theTodo: RandomAPI;
  private _apiURL = 'the_url_of_your_api';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this._apiURL).subscribe((data: RandomAPI) => {
      this.theTodo = data ;
    });
  }
}
```

Now the `theTodo` object has all your API data and you can access it as you wish.

```
// Array of entities data
this.entities = this.theTodo.responses.Detection.Entities 
console.log(this.entities) // Like as [{"entityId":"1","score":1.05855}]
```

More info: [ionic 4 get native data](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-native-http-get-empty-data-in-html/155086)

**Update:** I made a mistake on this last step, should be:

```
// Array of entities data
this.entities = this.theTodo.responses[0].Detection.Entities 
console.log(this.entities) // Like as [{"entityId":"1","score":1.05855}]
```

Comment: I already update my code at above. I already follow the step but get this error:  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Detection' of undefined

Comment: Oops! I made a mistake, `responses` is an array of `Response` types. So in order to access it, you must provide some index, like as `this.entities = this.theTodo.responses[0].Detection.Entities`.

Comment: can already, If I don't want to show like this [{"entityId":"1","score":1.05855}] I want to get 1.05855 only?

Comment: You need to loop over it in order to get each `score` property. Please checkout [Typescript Handbook Iterators and Generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) section.

Comment: use looping at html?

Comment: Yes, in case you need to display that. See [this ionic 4 question](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/angular-loop/108318). Also, please mark it as solved as you already got what you asked for.